# Delete signal/slot connection from Qt Designer

Tags: qt, qt-designer

How do I delete a signal/slot connection that I've created from Qt Designer? I created such a connection, but now it's no longer needed and I want to delete it.

I tried right-clicking on it, but the Delete action is disabled:

[image]

I can't use Select All because I have other signals/slots which I don't want to delete. Basically I can't select the connection to delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Inside `QtDesigner`, select `View->Signal/Slot Editor`. Select the connection you wish to delete and then click the big red minus icon.

EDIT:

Here's the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-connection-mode.html#editing-and-deleting-connections) describing what you need to do.

Comment: "Select the connection" - that's the problem. I can't select it. I left-click on it but it doesn't get selected.

Comment: You're looking in the wrong window. I've added a link to the documentation showing you the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue using PyQt5 and I can't click on the connection at all, despite what the documentation says to do. However, the signal/slot editor is another place you can delete them. It needs to be checked in the View section, and it should appear somewhere. Mine was in a tab at the bottom right corner. You can just click the connection you want to delete and press the minus button.

[Signal/slot editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZPy1.png)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1-> is where you can edit signals and slots (drag and drop) but if you wanna clear any connection , do step 2 and 3.

2-> right click here and check "signals and slots editor".(or go to menu and "view->views->signals and slots editr")

3-> in this place you can see connections that you added in step 1 , you can remove them! by the "-" button ( that is red there).